# -fno-objc-arc does not work for me

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I converted a non-ARC code to an ARC code. I added `-fno-objc-arc` in compiler flags to certain files that did not require ARC.

However, I am still receiving 50 errors INSIDE those files which are ARC errors.
What to do?

Comment: try to clean the project (Cmd+Shift+K), and tell us what errors do you get

Comment: Maybe you have some references inside those files to objects that have ARC activated?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819108/fno-objc-arc-not-working-to-disable-arc) might help you. Often times there is a dependency chain of files (through your `#import` statements) which causes problems in other files than the ones appearing in the error list. Trying adding -fno-objc-arc to some files that import the ones giving you errors.

Comment: We'll need to know more. What errors? What files? Are this standard files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [-fno-objc-arc not working to disable ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819108/fno-objc-arc-not-working-to-disable-arc)

Comment: I have added -fno-objc-arc  on all files except the ones that have ARC. Still not working. And the errors received are like - Retain not allowed in ARC.... Release not allowed in ARC. though i have added -fno-objc-arc  to all these files.

Comment: do you get that after cleaning the project, and project derived data?

Comment: yes... After cleaning it like 4-5 times and then running it gives errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it... I did it by adding

```
-fobjc-arc
```

to all the Compiler flags of files that require ARC. And adding

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

to Compiler flags of files that dont require ARC. And switching on the ARC for the project overall. It works for me.